# Live camera streaming in Node js and Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to live stream the data from one of our camera into the browser.I can connect to camera and converting RTSP to HLS using FFMPEG in Node JS. All the segments are written to local folder in Node JS. But how do i send this ReactJS continuously.

```
Backend
----->src
----->videos
        output.m3u8
        output1.ts
        output2.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HLS, the client simply requests the segments as it needs them.  You simply serve these files like any other static files, via any standard web server.

Comment: I could do that but since it is live streaming client has to read the folder that server is writing video segments.

Comment: @akarshhs No, it only needs to read your `output.m3u8`.  The client will repeatedly read this playlist to figure out which segments it needs.